# Definition of some sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to know what the sets $\mathbb{Z}^{[0,1]}$, $[0,1]^{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ are. So, could someone tell their definition. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usual for the set $A^B$ to denote the set of all functions $B\to A$.

Comment: You can think of the set $A^{\mathbb{Z}}$ as the set of all bi-infinite sequences whose elements are taken from $A$ as, after all,  a sequence is nothing more than an assignment of elements to each integer, which is exactly what a function from the integers is.